# Strings and specific symbols in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write some commands in Bash.
I have a part of this command in `hosts` var.

```
hosts="one-1.stend.st,one-2.stend.st"
hosts="{$hosts}" # I have to "bracket" this
```

The command is like this:

```
ipa service-allow-create....... hosts=$hosts
```

> error: {one-1.stend.st,one-2.stend.st} - no such entry

So yes, program understood brackets and all wrote but doesn't work.
When I write

```
ipa service-allow-create....... hosts={one-1.stend.st,one-2.stend.st}
```

all work as intended.

But I can't leave command like this. I have to somehow use `$hosts` and round it in brackets.

Help me please

Comment: I would have expected it exactly the other way around: The first form should pass the string `hosts={one-1.stend.st,one-2.stend.st}` **verbatim** as a last argument to `ipa` while the second form should undergo bash bracket expansion and create **two** arguments for `ipa`, that is `hosts=one-1.stend.st`  and then `hosts=one-2.stend.st`.

Comment: --hosts={client1.example.com,client2.example.com}

Comment: You can try calling it with `"${hosts}"` instead. Like: `ipa service-allow-create....... hosts="${hosts}"`. What's the result if you do that?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues the same result - no such entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I use variable `hosts="{one-1.stend.st,one-2.stend.st}"`

And just in the center of code I use

`/bin/bash << EOF`

`ipa .... --hosts=$hosts`

`EOF`

And all is working

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
hosts="{one-1.stend.st,one-2.stend.st}"
```

Looks like an obvious solution. Did you try that?

Comment: I have a lot of such one-i, so firstly I have to make this string by cycle, and later do `hosts={$hosts}`

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```sh
ipa service-allow-create....... hosts={one-1.stend.st,one-2.stend.st}
```

the shell expands that to

```sh
ipa service-allow-create....... hosts=one-1.stend.st hosts=one-2.stend.st
# ............................. ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is [3.5.1 Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion)

If you look at the order of [3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), notice that brace expansion happens **before** parameter expansion. You have to resort to `eval` to force a second round of evaluations, but that's generally not recommended.

Use an array here

```sh
myHosts=(
    one-1.stend.st
    one-2.stend.st
    two
    three
    etc
)
```

then use this expansion

```sh
ipa service-allow-create....... "${myHosts[@]/#/hosts=}"
```

Comment: it doesnt work, im sorry I forgot that it is `--hosts=`, it is an option

Comment: then `"${myHosts[@]/#/--hosts=}"`

Comment: yes, I did like this and it is not working

Comment: script is paused on that moment and waited me to enter it manually
`[member user]:`

Comment: This is beyond the scope of your question. Create a new one.

Comment: Maybe I should to find a way how ipa function parse this input?

Comment: Start with `man ipa`